# What is the United States' true 'real politik' position on the recent Armenian-Azerbaijan conflict?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, geopolitics, azerbaijan, armenia

The re-emergence of hostilities in 2020 between Armenia and Azerbaijan reportedly resulted in thousands of casualties for both sides; while I do not want to comment on the orgins of the conflict and who the aggressor was, I am curious as to what the United States' position was on the conflict. Note that I'm not talking about their publicly expressed opinion which was tacit neutrality, but the 'real politik' of the United States interests: does the State Department have a preference for either side? Did Azerbaijan make a deal with the United States to "allow" their victory in the conflict?

Certainly Russia appears to have expressed interest in protecting Armenia's territorial interest with their actions (this, despite Armenia's recent apparent hostility towards Russia), but I can't get a read on what the United States might prefer. I'm tempted to believe they tacitly approved the Azerbaijan offensive given Israel's involvement in supplying the Azerbaijan military with the so-called "suicide drones" among other shipments that occurred immediately before and during the conflict, but the geopolitical ramifications of Azerbaijan's victory (and what it cost them) are beyond me. I know that Washington has spent a lot of money and effort in influencing Armenia's politics recently in order to pull them away from Russia, but it seems counter productive to then allow this conflict to escalate as it did; United States language in other conflicts tends to be stronger with the threat of retaliation (see language on Ukraine for what I mean). Given the civilian casualties reportedly in the hundreds from the village bombardments, I expected a sterner response.

I'm especially curious to learn if perhaps another country asked the United States to not get involved (Turkey? Israel?) and if the United States' decision was influenced by that (and why).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the short answer is that Trump didn't care, but since it's hard to prove a negative... you'll have to wait some years (probably decades) until the Trump presidency files become publicly available at the National Archives. And even then, there are some concerns that Trump's presidency was non-standard in that record-keeping regard as well https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/17/historians-having-to-tape-together-records-that-trump-tore-up